# Input фокусировка | JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

Есть input:

```
<input class="placeholder" 
placeholder="Поиск по контактам" 
autocorrect="off" 
spellcheck="true" 
name="_search_input_name">
```

А также JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
       $('input[name=_search_input_name]')[0].focus();
    }, 1000);
```

Стили:

```
background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 6px;
    font: var(--body-font);
    color: var(--main-text-color);
```

Логически все верно и input должен фокусироваться, но этого не происходит. Как мне установить каретку внутрь input?

Answer (score 0):

Решение банальное. Все написано правильно, просто окно оладчика крало на себя фокус, вот я ничего и не мог получить)))